I am getting an error with AAB upload n google console
I am trying to upload my aab file for production and i get this error:
Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.xxx.aaa.
I am using eas to build the aab. This is my app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "aaa",
    "slug": "xxx",
    "package": "com.xxx.aaa",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/app-icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.xxx.aaa",
      "versionCode": 2
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-font"
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": ...
      }
    },
    "owner": ...
  }
}

I have defined my package name correctly but i still get an error.

This error message happens if you upload an APK or AAB that doesn't have the expected package name.
The config you shared suggests that you believe you've compiled with the right package name, so let me show you how to print the package name of the AAB and hopefully this puts you on the right track to identify where things went wrong.

Download bundletool.jar from https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases -- This is the opensource repo where Google publishes the tool to build and manipulate app bundles.

Run the following command:
java -jar bundletool.jar dump manifest --bundle /path/to/app.aab --xpath=/manifest/@package 

This will print the package name of the AAB, and if we're to trust the error message of the Play Console, will not be "com.xxx.aaa".


Hopefully, from there, you can find where this package name has been defined and you can update it appropriately.
